# Button clicker for website

Tags: javascript, button, numbers, click, counter

I need a button clicker. When I click on button, 0 turns to 1, if I click again , 1 turns to 2 etc.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work for me.

I need a code that work and that will remember amount of clicks even if I refresh tab or close it. This is code i've tried.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    int clicks = 0;
    function click() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="click()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into cookies?

Comment: Have i looked into cookies? I want to make something like Cookie-Clicker game on website, so the first step is this. :)

Comment: Ah, good, because cookies surely "will remember amount of clicks even if i refresh tab or close [the page]."

Comment: @StefanĐorđević check my code below, solved your problem of saving count;  LOCAL STORAGE  to the rescue

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no "int", it uses "var".

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0; // change int to var here
    function countClicks() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="countClicks()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: THIS CODE DOESNT WORK

Comment: `click` is a reserved JS function

Comment: it worked for me, anyway, you're absolutely right. I've changed the function name...

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your Click count to somewhere persistent and retrieve again when page is reloaded. Cookies is good place for that.

You can learn more about cookies [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Change `click()` to almost anything but that. I suggest `incrementClick()`. `click()` is a reserved function in JavaScript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks = 0;
    function incrementClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="incrementClick()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

For persisting the clicks across page refresh, I suggest using cookies to save the current value of the click variable, like this ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

Reading cookies:

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Demo with cookie support: http://jsbin.com/rekafi/4

---

**Note:** I suggest you move away from including inline JavaScript in your `<button>` element (e.g. `onClick="incrementClick()"`). Try to keep your JS separate from your HTML using jQuery, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving to localStorage

```
var clicks = parseInt( localStorage.getItem("clicks") || 0 ) ;

function bindThisToButtonClickHandler() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    localStorage.setItem("clicks", clicks) 
};
```

You can check the browser support here : http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE THAT WORKS**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="app1.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="clickdiv" >hello</div> 
  <button  onclick="countTracker()">Click me</button> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var clickCount = 0;
      function countTracker() {
          clickCount += 1;
          document.getElementById("clickdiv").innerHTML = "Clicks:" + clickCount;
          localStorage.setItem("count", clickCount);

      }
      str_count = localStorage.getItem("count");
      console.log(str_count);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Care to explain where you got the idea to change the function name to `clickFun()` to the OP? :)

Comment: @Drakes clickFun is a bad name but using click() it was not working. My understanding is "click" is a reserved word, it cannot be used as function name.